# Mac Automator Twitter Scrape Shell Script to Run Python Stopped Working

Tags: bash, shell, python, osx-el-capitan, automator

OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
I have Mac Calendar calling an Automator app to launch a shell script that opens a python file that scrapes a few Twitter handles and presents them to me as a web page. This was all well and good up until about two weeks ago. It suddenly stopped working giving this error (seen when running inside Automator)

> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

By not working I think I mean the requests.get(url) is getting shut down immediately on Twitter only (same script works on other urls). Various Googling led me to think it has something to do with Twitter robots.txt, as I know the app is hitting Twitter before I get the error (Little Snitch tells me).
**But why when I run from the terminal as a python file does it work fine, but not when the same python file is called by a shell script?** Anyone have ideas or a workaround?